# Split page into columns

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

How do I split the page???

I don't get how you move web parts side by side. Im guessing im suppose to add columns somehow, or a table layout. But can not see any options to do so.

Im new to Sharepoint, and its driving me mad. :|

Ive read that you can do it using sharepoint designer. This doesnt work on my machine, as it says it must be running a foundation server.

And how would I then load the templates in anyway.

[image: Layout example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the type of page your dealing with

**Wiki Page**
These are the pages where you in edit mode can insert web parts as part of the text.

On Wiki Pages you can change text layout when in edit mode:
[image]
New layouts can't be made

**Web Part Page**
These are the pages where you only can insert web parts into zones and you're not using publishing.

On Web Part Pages you can only select layout when you create the page. (You can then edit it using SharePoint designer later)

New layouts can only be made by changing pages using SharePoint Designer

**Publishing Page**
These are the pages using page layout on a publishing site.

On Publishing pages you can change Page Layouts when in edit mode:
[image]
New Page layouts can be made using SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio (or any editor) and Save/Deployed/uploaded in Master Page Gallery

Comment: Do you know any good tutorials on how to create pages in Visual Studio(2012). Im struggling to find Anything at all. Or can I use the designer on a sharepoint server (not foundaation) somehow. Thanks.

Comment: Which kind of page do you want to create? And yes SharePoint designer works fine wieh SharePoint Server unless the administrators has disabled it (and you have the rights to use it)

Comment: Ive been able to via the website, expand the edit option, to click edit with sharepoint designer 2013, which I just installed. I then created a layout to use on my site. When I create the layout, its all in code (html etc). Where is the actual design view gone?

Comment: Due to the dynamic and flexible nature of pages in SP2013 MS has decided that the Design view didn't make sense and therefore they removed it

Answer (score 1):

While creating a webpart page you have options to select which layout you want to use. According to the screenshot provided you can have 2 columns webpart zone. Then in the webpart zones you can add your webparts according to your requirement.

Comment: Oh, so its on page creation only? No way of changing an existing page's layout? I'll give it a try tomorrow cheers.

Comment: you can change the existing page layout through sharepoint designer. Unfortunately you don't have access to that.